# Can't compile SFML + ImGui using GCC

Tags: c++, windows, sfml, imgui

Since I started learning SFML, I found a lot hard to include libraries in CPP.

The two easiest ways I found was configuring Visual Studio like the tutorial, or configuring CMake with CLion.

But I don't like Visual Studio, CLion is really heavy on the machine and I just can't undestand CMake.

So I started working with VSCode and making .bat files and mingw32 g++ to build and run:

`g++ ../main.cpp -o ../build/main.exe -I ${SFML_DIR}\include -L ${SFML_DIR}\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

This is the simplest for build I made, considering that the .bat file is inside and scrips folder and I want the build to be in root/build and to be named main.exe. Then I can run it using another .bat file:

`"../build/main.exe"`

But, for compiling it together with ImGui I'm having some problems, I try to run:

`g++ ../main.cpp -o ../build/main.exe -I ${IMGUI-DIR} -L ${IMGUI-DIR} -I ${IMGUI-DIR}\backends -L ${IMGUI-DIR}\backends -I ${IMGUI-SFML-DIR} -L ${IMGUI-SFML-DIR} -I ${SFML-DIR}\include -L ${SFML-DIR}\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32`

But I always get this error:

> AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `ImGui::SFML::Init(sf::RenderWindow&, bool)' AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to` ImGui::SFML::ProcessEvent(sf::Event const&)'
> AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `ImGui::SFML::Update(sf::RenderWindow&, sf::Time)' AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to` ImGui::Begin(char const*, bool*, int)'
> AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e6): undefined reference to `ImGui::ColorEdit3(char const*, float*, int)' AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to` ImGui::InputText(char const*, char*, unsigned int, int, int (*)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData*), void*)'
> AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3ec): undefined reference to `ImGui::Button(char const*, ImVec2 const&)' AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x44a): undefined reference to` ImGui::End()'
> AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `ImGui::SFML::Render(sf::RenderWindow&)' AppData\Local\Temp\ccogESXd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x48f): undefined reference to` ImGui::SFML::Shutdown()'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and if someone has suggestions or tips of a better way of doing all of this, will be apreciated :)

Comment: Looks like you are only compiling main.cpp and not compiling all of the source files for imgui into your executable.

Comment: Do I need to? I thought that ImGui was just included as it is with SFML...

Comment: SFML has libraries. For imgui irections [here](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui#usage) say ***No specific build process is required. You can add the .cpp files to your existing project.***

Comment: Ok, my bad then. Will try that and comeback with a response.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by creating a folder called "include" inside the root of the project, putting all .h and .cpp files from imgui and imgui-sfml inside it and running the following 3 line command:

> g++ -c ../include/*.cpp -I ../include -L ../include -I C:\SFML\include -L C:\SFML\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32

> g++ -c ../main.cpp -I ../include -L ../include -I C:\SFML\include -L C:\SFML\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32

> g++ *.o -o ../build/main.exe -I C:\SFML\include -L C:\SFML\lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32

Thanks to @drescherjm for the comments, it really helped me!